# Is there a way to add additional information to a RDF triple?

Tags: sparql, rdf

I have documents represented by RDF triples and some users can add relationships between those documents. The way I plan to record those relationships is following: (subset of RDF/XML code)

```
<rdf:Description rdf:about="SOURCEDocId">
    <kb:tocMember rdf:resource="TARGETDocId"/>
</rdf:Description>

<rdf:Description rdf:about="TARGETDocId">
    <kb:isInToc rdf:resource="SOURCEDocId"/>
</rdf:Description>
```

(relationships are established in a Table Of Content, so tocMember and isInToc names).

But I now need to store the UserId who created this relationship. One heretic way could be to add an attrubute, something as:

```
<rdf:Description rdf:about="SOURCEDocId">
    <kb:tocMember xml:createdBy="USERId" rdf:resource="TARGETDocId"/>
</rdf:Description>

<rdf:Description rdf:about="TARGETDocId">
    <kb:isInToc xml:createdBy="USERId" rdf:resource="SOURCEDocId"/>
</rdf:Description>
```

I am not sure this will be accepted by RDF triplestores and also this information cannot be used in SPARQL requests. 
There is also the possibility to create a link entity and qualify it but this is a mess for a very small requirement to implement. 
So a better way?

Comment: Check out the available provenance methods: RDF reification, singleton property, RDF* and other approaches such as the one of Wikidata.

Comment: `xml:createdBy="USERId"` - what is that? RDF is not XML ... eitehr reifiication or n-ary relations - that's it.

Comment: By the way, showing RDF data as XML is worst case in my opinion. What not using more readable formats like N-Triples, Turtle etc. ? There is more than RDF/XML available

Comment: "xml:createdBy="USERId"" was said in my question as an heretic thing. And RDF/XML the simpliest way to expose the case

Answer (score 1):

Statements about statements can be represented in RDF by:

1) RDF reification

2) n-ary relations

3) Singleton property

4) named graph

5) using RDF*

Each option has advantages and disadvantages.

Here's how your case will be represented using RDF reification (the example is with the first statement):

```
:SOURCEDocId-tocMember-TARGETDocId
  rdf:type rdf:Statement ;
  :createdBy :USERId ;
  rdf:object :TARGETDocId ;
  rdf:predicate kb:tocMember ;
  rdf:subject :SOURCEDocId .
```

As commented, using Turle makes it clear and readable. Yet, since you gave the example in RDF/XML, the reification would look like this, serialized in XML:

```
  <rdf:Statement rdf:ID="SOURCEDocId-tocMember-TARGETDocId">
    <createdBy rdf:resource="#USERId"/>
    <rdf:subject rdf:resource="#SOURCEDocId"/>
    <rdf:predicate rdf:resource="http://example.org/kb/tocMember"/>
    <rdf:object rdf:resource="#TARGETDocId"/>
  </rdf:Statement>
```

In practice statements are often not given URI, but left as blank nodes:

```
[
  rdf:type rdf:Statement ;
  :createdBy :USERId ;
  rdf:object :TARGETDocId ;
  rdf:predicate kb:tocMember ;
  rdf:subject :SOURCEDocId .
]
```

Here `:createdBy` is shown as locally created but it would of course be better if you reuse a property from appropriate vocabulary, such as `dc:creator` from Dublic Core or `schema:creator` from schema.org .

With option (2), you would not directly link your source to your target but through an intermediary node, say `:targetEntry1`, which you can then relate to  values and provenance:

```
:SOURCEDocId kb:tocMember :targetEntry1 . 
:targetEntry1 :value :TARGETDocId ;
     :createdBy :USERId .
```